# how to view/edit files uploaded to Azure webapp?

Tags: python, azure, flask, web-applications

I got my first flask webapp (*hello.py*) working (deployed) on Azure. I want to add more functionality to this webapp. According to documentation I am following
(https://medium.com/@nikovrdoljak/deploy-your-flask-app-on-azure-in-3-easy-steps-b2fe388a589e)
I should test my files (hello.py, home.html etc) locally and use `git push` to send new files to Azure cloud. I should restart my application to see changes.

(1) Is there a way to edit these files on Azure cloud using say emacs ?
(2) Related to (1) on which path do these files exist on Azure ? I clicked on cloudshell and a terminal popped up. It is apparently my home directory. I can see only one directory (clouddrive). I cannot see hello.py. I also went to .scm.azurewebsites.net and clicked on bash. I do get a command prompt but cannot see hello.py.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under Development Tools you should have App Service Editor (Preview)

If you click on that it should allow you to edit the files via the portal.

[image]